# ./aconfigure: Permission Denied Error in Compiling pjsip for ios 7

Tags: ios, pjsip

I am trying to compile PJSIP2.3 for iOS on Mac 10.10.1(Xcode 6.1). But I'm getting some errors when I run ./configure-iphone.

Below are the errors shown in terminal:

```
WifiMacBook:pjproject-2.3 apple$ ./configure-iphone
configure-iphone: DEVPATH is not specified, using /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
configure-iphone: IPHONESDK is not specified, choosing iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
configure-iphone: CC is not specified, choosing /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
configure-iphone: ARCH is not specified, choosing -arch armv7
configure-iphone: CXX is not specified, using /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
configure-iphone: calling ./aconfigure with env vars:
CC = /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
CXX = /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
 CFLAGS = -O2 -Wno-unused-label -DPJ_SDK_NAME="\"iPhoneOS7.0.sdk\"" -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
LDFLAGS = -O2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation
AR = /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -o
RANLIB = echo ranlib
./configure-iphone: line 147: ./aconfigure: Permission denied
```

I see this link for comping pjsip
http://gaurav-iphone.blogspot.in/2011/09/compiling-pjsip.html

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Give full permission to your pjsip directory,

**`chmod 777 *`**

Then type below command in your terminal,

**`$ tr -d '\r' <configure-iphone> FILE.new`**

**`$ rm configure-iphone`**

**`$ mv FILE.new configure-iphone`**

- Again run

**`$ ./configure-iphone`**

Happy to help all :)

Answer (score 0):

Is `aconfigure` executable? Try to run `chmod -x aconfigure` to solve this situation.

It might also be the file permission.